# How to retrieve a list of object in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

My code of retrieving is:

```
public List<ItemImages> getAllItemImages(int index, int max) {
    Session session = currentSession();

    List<ItemImages> items = session.createCriteria( ItemImages.class )
                    .setMaxResults(max)
                    .setFirstResult(index)
                    .list();

    System.out.println("list size: " + items.size());
    return items;
}
```

The problem the I have is my items.size() = 0. What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I modify the hql query"?

Comment: Sorry, it is fault statement

Comment: The problem may be that there is no data, that `max` is set to zero or that `index` is too high.

Comment: My index is 0 and max is 10. My table definitely have date because I have added some while debugging this

Comment: Can you add `hibernate.show_sql=true` to your `hibernate.cfg.xml ` to see what that SQL query looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Check your entity for `ItemImages` java code and to which table this entity is mapped to.

If the mapping is correct and if you have data in your table then Hibernate will get the data if you use criteria queries.

Here is a simple example to test this feature:

`ItemImages` entity:

```
@Entity
public class ItemImages {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    // Constructor, Setters & Getters
}
```

Here is the sample code to test using criteria queries:

**Saving ItemImages:**

```
private static void saveItemImages() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    ItemImages i1 = new ItemImages("i1");
    ItemImages i2 = new ItemImages("i2");
    ItemImages i3 = new ItemImages("i3");
    ItemImages i4 = new ItemImages("i4");
    session.save(i1);
    session.save(i2);
    session.save(i3);
    session.save(i4);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Getting data using criteria query, I am passing index as `0` and `max` as `2`:

```
public static List<ItemImages> getAllItemImages(int index, int max) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();

    List<ItemImages> items = session.createCriteria( ItemImages.class )
                    .setMaxResults(max)
                    .setFirstResult(index)
                    .list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("list size: " + items.size());
    return items;
}
```

**Output of this code:**

list size: 2

Query generated by Hibernate for this criteria:

```
select * from ( select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.name as name2_0_0_ 
from ItemImages this_ ) where rownum <= ?
```